# Maven clean fails

Tags: maven

I really am having trouble with running Maven clean on my Java project, so not sure what to do anymore. I am very new to Maven and working on an existing project and trying to setup the environment on my PC.

Setup:

- Maven 2.2
- Java7
- Added all environment paths (M2, M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME)

Problem:

```
Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin
POM Location: C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.2\maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin at C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-clean-plugin\2.2\maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
```

After maven clean the content of maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom is the following:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center></hr>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried:
- copying the maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom from official website
- deleting everything in repository (.m2/repository)
- taking the sources again (new repository)
- ???

Really at a loss what to do anymore, I would appreciate your help.

Why is it doing that? What should I see in the file maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom and it instead updates to something that triggers error ?

Comment: did u find the solution?

Comment: Yes, I should close this question somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM error was being triggered by a

---

tag which was not closed in the m2 repository. I fixed the HTML markup and the POM error did not show anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)? [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html) is also a good point to start.

The [Maven Clean Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/) is one of [Maven's core plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html). You definitely should NOT use its `.pom` as you did it (downloading it manually).

The content of the `.pom` you mention is the HTML page that is shown in case of an [HTTP status code 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Since you mention Maven 2.2 I guess your project is rather old. Apparently the location of the core plugins has changed since and the redirect to the new location doesn't work. What's set in your [`<mirrors>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) section of your [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)?

Why do you use Maven 2.2? The [current stable version is 3.2.3](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).

Comment: I am only trying to setup the environment by cloning a project that already exists. So not sure why Maven is outdated, but it seems to work well for their project. I read the instructions to POM but the folder .m2 is still a mystery for me...

Comment: The `.m2` folder contains your local repository. It contains a local copy of _all_ artifacts you (or Maven itself) ever used/resolved or built/installed while running a Maven build. See [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

Comment: This should be in Maven folder..  I will have a look asap and let you know what's writter in the mirrors tag (but this is will be in some hours from now since I don't have access to the source code atm). Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: <mirrors>
- <!--  mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     
  --> 
  </mirrors>